# Zend frame work Custom view helper error

Tags: zend-framework

Hi am trying to add custom helper throughout my application

Have done following steps

1. index.php

   ```
   $view = new Zend_View();
   $view->addHelperPath('My/View/Helper', 'My_View_Helper');
   Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addHelper($viewRenderer);
   ```
2. Helper class in My/View/Helper

   ```
   class My_View_Helper_Common extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract
   {

       public function example()
       {
         return "ok"; 
       }
   }
   ```
3. now calling in view index.phtml

   ```
   $this->example()
   ```

am getting this error

```
Uncaught exception 'Zend_View_Exception' with message 'script 'error/error.phtml' not found in path (.\application\views\scripts\)' in C:\xampp\htdocs\wyfixture\library\Zend\View\Abstract.php:924 
Stack trace: 
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\wyfixture\library\Zend\View\Abstract.php(827): Zend_View_Abstract->_script('error/error.pht...') 
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\wyfixture\library\Zend\Controller\Action\Helper\ViewRenderer.php(903): Zend_View_Abstract->render('error/error.pht...') 
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\wyfixture\library\Zend\Controller\Action\Helper\ViewRenderer.php(924): Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_ViewRenderer->renderScript('error/error.pht...', NULL) 
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\wyfixture\library\Zend\Controller\Action\Helper\ViewRenderer.php(963): Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_ViewRenderer->render() 
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\wyfixture\library\Zend\Controller\Action\HelperBroker.php(277): Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_ViewRenderer->postDispatch() 
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\wyfixture\library\Zend\Controller\Action.php(523):
```

please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you have two problems here:

1. Your 'application/views/scripts/error/error.phtml' is missing. You can restore it and you'll get more accurate exception message at once.
2. Your helper class should contain a method named after the helper.

So, in your case it's file `My/View/Helper/Example.php` with the following body

```
class My_View_Helper_Example extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract {
  public function example() {...}
}
```

Then you'll be able to call it from the view with

```
$this->example()
```

Comment: Thanks Vika ,

It's working now.

But can we add only one method in a view helper?

say if am adding two method like this :

class My_View_Helper_Common extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract
{
   
    public function common()
    {
      return "ok"; 
    }

   public function example()
    {
      return "ok"; 
    }


and if am calling method $this->example(). It's giving same error. 
but ok for $this->common();

Or there is different way to all example in view .

Please help me. am newbie to zend and I have to understand all these.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to Vikas answer.

To call more than one method in a view helper you can use code like this:

In `My/View/Helper/Example.php`

```
class My_View_Helper_Example extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract
{
    public function example()
    {
        return $this;
    }

    public function foo()
    {
        return 'foo';
    }

    public function bar()
    {
        return 'bar';
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->foo();
    }
}
```

In you views:

```
echo $this->example()->foo() // prints foo
echo $this->example()->bar() // prints bar
echo $this->example() // prints foo
```

Comment: vasim: do not forget to upvote helpful answers. See the FAQ ;)